# Submitting a web form

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, python-requests

I'm trying to post a comment to a web article with python's `requests` library. I know there are countless threads on submitting a POST request but somehow my comment does not show up.

Here is my code:

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.polskatimes.pl/fakty/polityka/a/strajk-oznacza-uderzenie-opozycja-zapowiada-protesty-13-grudnia-zdjecia,11555853/#art-komentarze'
params = dict(
    autor='John',
    temat='Good job!',
    tresc='I approve this message. #Trump2016',
)
resp = requests.post(url, data=params, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/4.0', 'Host': 'www.polskatimes.pl', 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': 1, 'Referer': url.replace('/#art-komentarze', '')})
print(resp.url)
```

Im wondering whether you could make it work?

Comment: Are you calling a RESTful API?

Comment: what's the error you get?

Comment: @ettanany I'm not quite sure; not getting an error. The code just doesn't deliver.

Comment: You can not send your request that way, you need to find another approach, that url is not an endpoint for a restful service.

Comment: The url, params, and headers are what gets send to the server when I "inspect with firebug".